# How to go about working with professionals online if you're developing a new encyrption algorithm?

Tags: encryption, algorithm

I am currently a Computer Science student working on my Master's and think I've discovered a new form of encryption (by extreme luck). Though I've heard it said many times that unless one is well versed in cryptography they shouldn't even attempt to develop anything crypto related, both I and my Committee Chair (to a lesser extent) believe my algorithm can work.

That being said, the algorithm requires knowledge in a field of mathematics both I and my Committee Chair are uncomfortable in and I was wondering how I would go about working with professionals in that field online?

I am not looking to make money on my algorithm nor work in cryptography, as it doesn't interest me much. However, I'm slightly worried about reaching out to professionals who seem very willing / eager to help, but who also have many patents / highly respected careers in this particular domain of mathematics (as I've been in loose contact with one such person).

Comment: The first sentence of the second paragraph of the [Memo to the Amateur Cipher Designer](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/1998/1015.html#cipherdesign) sums it up: "Unfortunately, you have a tough road ahead of you."  That said, there's no harm in trying.   If you've identified folks who have the expertise to help, by all means reach out to them and ask for help.  Just don't be disappointed when most of them aren't interested.  All you need is a few (or one) who are.

Comment: The NIST has a contest about this right? That's how "Rain doll" (Rijndael) is used now. I read that a long time ago in [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) (I'm pretty sure you know what AES is, but in the Spanish version (Español) are the votes on every part of the contest and how I found about it)

Comment: @Azteca It did, in 1997.  No similar NIST-sponsor contest is on the visible horizon.  The latest non-NIST similar content is CEASAR, which started in 2012 and is now in the third round.  Additionally, Rijndael was designed by Joan Daemen and Vincent Rijman who were both well known and well respected cryptographers before the AES competition.

Comment: I think the field of using proven hard algorithms is yet open. Both from the discrete inverse logarithmic problem and the prim factorisation problem isn't proven that they are hard. An NP-complete problem should be used for ciphering.

Comment: @Azteca: I'm actually planning on submitting my algorithm to NIST as a Post Quantum Proof Encryption algorithm, as the encryption is unlike anything out there today.

Whether it is indeed Quantum Proof or not, who knows (my Professor thinks that, since the algorithm lies within the binary world - as it requires the use of computers, that it isn't Quantum Proof). 

That being said, would the fact that I was planning on submitting this to NIST help me in any way?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, why you do not submit your academic work in a top cryptology conference or journal. This will guarantee it is reviewed and questioned by cryptology experts.  A side note it is unlikely that your algorithm work since you mentioned [extreme luck], [you and your supervisor do not really have the necessary mathematical background to validate your work], [cryptography doesn't interest you]. Luck it not enough :)

Comment: ObRef if you haven't, you should ask at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ which is a more appropriate venue for your question than this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simple conversations with experts in the field to start with. Once you are more certain of the unknowns, prepare to file for a patent. In doing this, you'd research existing patents to make sure yours is unique. Once your patent is filed, post it on here or crypto or journals/etc to get feedback from the community of experts. You can skip the patent if you dont care about money or attribution.